# Eclipse has problems with log4cplus?

Tags: java, eclipse, autodesk, log4cplus

This has been annoying me for the past month or so. I haven't changed anything internally AFAIK, but suddenly my JFileChoosers started logging this whenever I clicked on a directory to open it:

```
l o g 4 c p l u s : E R R O R  N o   a p p e n d e r s   c o u l d   b e   f o u n d   f o r   l o g g e r   ( A d S y n c N a m e s p a c e ) .
l o g 4 c p l u s : E R R O R   P l e a s e   i n i t i a l i z e   t h e   l o g 4 c p l u s   s y s t e m   p r o p e r l y .
```

The less spaced out text (the spaced out text is how it appears in console) looks like this:

```
log4cplus:ERROR No appenders could be found for logger (AdSyncNamespace).
log4cplus:ERROR Please initialize the log4cplus system properly.
```

Google turns up nothing but log4j results, so I'm really stuck.

Comment: Do you have Autocad or anything from the company installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your problem is the same one as reported on the [Qt development forum](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/29173) and on [Autodesk forum](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Installation-Hardware-OS/log4cplus-ERROR/td-p/4290303). Uninstalling Autodesk 360 should fix it.

Comment: Ouch. I really need Inventor, but I'll do so and see what happens.
-edit: Do I need 360 for Inventor?